# Django Models- Alternative for repetitive null=True, blank=True

Tags: django, django-models

I have Django models with many **uncompulsory fields** Is there an alternative to avoid `null=True` and `blank=True` ? Is there something like `blank_fields = ('email','image',)` and `null_fields = ('email', 'image')` ?

Comment: Are those fields `CharField`? If yes, then you should reconsider using only `blank=True`. Your idea might look nice, but it doesn't really bring advantages. It means just outsourcing of the constraints specifications to another application part, making your code less readable.

Comment: Yeah you are right.Readability is more important than Convenience here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing which Django provides by default. These attributes are per field definitions, not something which is Model level. You have definitions as `unique_together`, `index_together` which are model level definitions combining different fields.

One approach can be of subclassing the Fields and provide a default definition -

```
class CustomIntegerField(models.IntegerField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['blank'] = True
        kwargs['null'] = True
        super(CustomIntegerField, self).__init__(**kwargs)


class Test(models.Model):
    cus = CustomIntegerField(default=0)
```

Migration:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [ ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Test',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('cus', test.models.CustomIntegerField(blank=True, default=0, null=True)),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

You can do this for other fields as well.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works. But I will stick to null=True and blank=True because of readability

Answer (score 3):

No, Django does not have any options like `blank_fields` or `null_fields`.

You could subclass the fields to create optional versions, e.g. `OptionalCharField`, but I would recommend against this. It might be less repetitive than using `blank=True, null=True` repeatedly, but it will be less readable for other Django developers who look at your code. And as Cezar suggests in the comments you shouldn’t usually use `null=True` for `CharField` because that means you have two empty values, `''` and `None`.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works but I agree that blank=true and null= true is better